# Point DNS to IP address with a port

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, dns

I can't point my DNS to a IP address that has a port other than port 80 (ie. 1.2.3.4:84) with "A Record". I can use "URL Redirect Record" though but that displays the IP address in the URL bar instead of the domain name I chose. How do I configure nginx to arrive at an IP address but change the URL to display the domain name I want instead of an IP address.

Comment: DNS has nothing to do with ports. When a client wants to connect to `http://domain:84`, it uses DNS to resolve only the `domain` portion. If you want `http://domain:80` to redirect to port 84, you don't use DNS for that, you use an HTTP redirect instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ... except SRV records that do encode ports but unfortunately browsers just ignore them.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek that is because browsers don't request SRV records, they request A/AAAA records instead. SRV records are used for service discovery protocols, not for HTTP

Comment: @RemyLebeau which is what I said... and SRV records could technically be used by web browsers like any other protocol, there is nothing that says that ports 80 and 443 are magical and could not be treated exactly as all others are. SRV records were not adopted by browsers not purely on technical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nginx to host my website so I could simply add multiple servers/server_names to port 80 instead of using multiple ports.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name